# How to get clicked list attribute value

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my menu list HTML:

```
<div id="sidebar-left">
                <ul class="nav main-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu" name="Home">
                        <a href="/employee/Home" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Home</span>
                        </a>                       
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu" name="Documents">
                        <a href="/documents/doc_details" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Documents</span>
                        </a>                       
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu" name="Pay">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Pay &amp; Benifits</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children" class="ng-scope" name="Slips">
                                <a href="/pay/paymanagement">slips</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                    
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Whenever I click the menu page will be reloaded and navigated to clicked `href`.
when page gets refreshed,menus will be loaded again.

Here am trying to get clicked menu `name attribute value` using current `url`.
So I have written this code

```
//pageUrl=location.pathname;
pageUrl="/pay/paymanagement"
$('#sidebar-left .nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').attr('name');
```

Here I have hard coded the `pageUrl`.
Now my problem is,whenever I click the `/pay/paymanagement` menu I should get name attribute value `Slips` right?but am getting `Pay` here. (i.e ) it returns its parent `li name attribute value`.

I have tried these methods also..

```
$('#sidebar-left .nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').closest('li').attr('name');

$('#sidebar-left .nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').parent('li').attr('name');
```

Everything returns `Slips` only.

How can I get current `li name attribute value` using only `url`.
Any suggestion?

`Note:` I can find out the clicked element using url only.I cant use any click events here.

Comment: Try this one: $('#sidebar-left .nav li:has(a[href="' + pageUrl + '"])').attr('name');

Comment: @Mittal please check my question fully.I have mentioned your answer also.

Comment: can you add your click event on the OP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#sidebar-left .nav li > a[href="' + pageUrl + '"]').parent().attr('name');
```

Descending to the child and then stepping back up works better

Comment: but its returning `undefined`

Comment: Try the new one

Answer (score 1):

Here, you get the 2 li elements so you need to select the last one to get the proper data:

**Solution 1:**

```
$(($('#sidebar-left .nav li:has(a[href="/pay/paymanagement"])')[1])).attr('name')
```

**Solution 2:**

```
$('#sidebar-left .nav li:has(a[href="/pay/paymanagement"])').last().attr('name')
```

JsFidder link: https://jsfiddle.net/m8z06nzc/1/

Answer (score 1):

try this, remove the `has`, and get the `closest`

check this https://jsfiddle.net/nruzrx85/1/

```
$('#sidebar-left .nav li a[href="' + pageUrl + '"]').closest('li').attr('name');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can send the value of name attribute in URL with query string. Then you can get the value of that query string using below function.

```
function getParameterByName(name, url) {
if (!url) url = window.location.href;
name = name.replace(/[\[\]]/g, "\\$&");
var regex = new RegExp("[?&]" + name + "(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)"),
    results = regex.exec(url);
if (!results) return null;
if (!results[2]) return '';
return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, " "));
```

}

Here I attach updated HTML code.

```
    <div id="sidebar-left">
                <ul class="nav main-menu">
                    <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu" name="Home">
                        <a href="/employee/Home" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Home</span>
                        </a>                       
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu" name="Documents">
                        <a href="/documents/doc_details" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Documents</span>
                        </a>                       
                    </li>
                    <li class="dropdown ng-scope" ng-repeat="parent in menu" name="Pay">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle">
                            <span class="hidden-xs ng-binding">Pay &amp; Benifits</span>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                           <li ng-repeat="child in parent.children" class="ng-scope" name="Slips">
                                <a href="/pay/paymanagement?name=slips">slips</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>                    
                </ul>
</div>
```